# ListView displaying items wrongly

Tags: android, listview

In my application I am using a listview which displays the data from a CustomAdapter.In my arraylist I have two items.My listview shows the last added data two times instead of first item.
This is my custom Adapter:

```
public class NodeListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Activity mActivity;
    ArrayList<Node> mNodeList;
    double mRecvProgress;
    double mSentProgress;
    String repeatSentprogress;
    String repeatRecvprogress;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Node node;
    public NodeListViewCustomAdapter(Activity aContext,Node node,ArrayList<Node> nodeList){
        super();
        mActivity = aContext;
        this.node = node;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)aContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mNodeList = nodeList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNodeList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtViewnodeTitle;
        TextView sentStatustxtView;
        TextView recvStatustxtView;
        TextView msgsentvalue;
        TextView msgrecvvalue;
        TextView sentindicator;
        TextView recvindicator;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nodelistitem_row, null);
        }   else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
            if(node.advertise)
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            node.advertise = false;
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.txtViewnodeTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewnodeTitle);
            holder.sentStatustxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sentstatustxtView);
            holder.recvStatustxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recvstatustextView);
            holder.msgsentvalue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgsenttitle);
            holder.msgrecvvalue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgrecvtitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.sentStatustxtView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.recvStatustxtView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        computeProgress();
        holder.txtViewnodeTitle.setText(String.valueOf(node.nodeID));
        holder.msgsentvalue.setText("< "+String.valueOf(node.ms)+"/"+node.MS);
        holder.sentStatustxtView.setText(repeatSentprogress);
        holder.msgrecvvalue.setText("> "+String.valueOf(node.mr)+"/"+node.MR);
        holder.recvStatustxtView.setText(repeatRecvprogress);
        return convertView;
    }
    private void computeProgress() {
        mSentProgress = ((double)node.ms/(double)node.MS)*20;
        mRecvProgress = ((double)node.mr/(double)node.MR)*20;
        repeatSentprogress = new String(new char[(int)mSentProgress]).replace('\0', (char) 9608);
        repeatRecvprogress = new String(new char[(int)mRecvProgress]).replace('\0', (char) 9608);
        if(node.ms == node.MS)holder.sentStatustxtView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else holder.sentStatustxtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        if(node.mr == node.MR)holder.recvStatustxtView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else holder.recvStatustxtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

This is my Activity:

```
public class Nodes extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView mListView;
    NodeListViewCustomAdapter mNodeListAdapter;
    public  ArrayList <Node> mNodesList ;
    TextView nodeIdView; 
    Timer mTimer;
    Timer mInnerTimer;
    int delay = 500;
    int period = 500;
    boolean found = false; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nodes);
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.node_list);
        mNodesList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        doTimerTask();
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    private void doTimerTask() {
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while(true){
                            try{
                                String PeardOutput = null; 
                                synchronized(AndroidPeardServer.nodestatsqe){
                                    PeardOutput = AndroidPeardServer.nodestatsqe.poll();
                                    if (PeardOutput == null) return; 
                                }
                                String msg  = PeardOutput.substring(3); 
                                process_nodeStats(msg); 
                                mNodeListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, delay, period);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    }
    private void process_nodeStats(String msg) {
        String[] nodeStats = msg.split(":");
        String  type    = nodeStats[0];
        int     nodeID  = Integer.parseInt(nodeStats[1]);
        int     value   = Integer.parseInt(nodeStats[2]); 
        int     cycle   = Integer.parseInt(nodeStats[3]);

        // Iterate through the nodelist
        found = false; 
        for(Node node: mNodesList){
            if (node.nodeID != nodeID) {
                continue;
            }
            else found = true; 
            populateNode(node,type, nodeID, value, cycle);
            mNodeListAdapter = new NodeListViewCustomAdapter(getParent(),node,mNodesList);
            mListView.setAdapter(mNodeListAdapter); 
            break; 
        }
        if (!found){
            Node node = new Node();         
            mNodesList.add(node);
            populateNode(node,type,nodeID,value,cycle);
            mNodeListAdapter = new NodeListViewCustomAdapter(getParent(),node,mNodesList);
            mListView.setAdapter(mNodeListAdapter); 
        }
    }
    private void populateNode(Node node,String type,int nodeId, int value, int cycle) {

        node.nodeID = nodeId;
        if(type.equals("MS")){
            node.MS = value;
            node.CS = cycle;
            node.ms = 0;
        }else if(type.equals("MR")){
            node.MR = value;
            node.CR = cycle;
            node.mr = 0;
        }else if(type.equals("ms")){
            if(cycle==node.CS) node.ms = + value;
            else node.ms = value;
        }else if(type.equals("mr")){
            if(cycle==node.CR) node.mr = + value;
            else node.mr = value;
        }else if (type.equals("NL")){
            mNodesList.remove(node);
        }else if(type.equals("NA")){
            node.advertise = true;
        }
    }


    //========= Node class to store in NodeList =================
    public  class Node {
         int nodeID;
         int MS; //Total Messages to Send to nodeID 
         int ms; //number of Messages sent so far
         int MR ; //Total Messages expected from nodeID
         int mr; //number of Messages received so far
         int CS; //Investigation Cycle for Sending
         int CR; //Investigation Cycle for Receiving
         boolean advertise = false; // To know the advertisements received
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the god feeling you forgot to paste some brackets around `if(node.advertise)` e.g./

Comment: I purposely done it since if condition for the single statement only

Comment: Ugly. Furthermore the indentation suggest differently. Also for me at least it is more logical to not span just the next statement. ALWAYS place curly braces for ifs!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Will do it in the future.Can you tell me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got tit right.I have not taken the node from the arraylist.So this line done it for me.

```
node = mNodeList.get(position);
```

Thanks for all.